# Is there a limit to how many extra attacks I can have in D&D 3.5?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, combat, critical-hit

I'm playing a fighter/warblade with the Lightning Maces and Power Critical feats, and the Blood in the Water stance, so **every time I score a crit, I have an immediate additional strike with the same bonus.** But with Blood in the Water, every time I land a crit, my attack damage and roll increase by 1.

So **is there a limit of how many additional extra attacks I can gain?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### No, there is no hard limit.

I can’t really cite any rules on this, other than to say that I am quite confident that no one will ever be able to cite a rule that enforces any such limit.

Of course, you’re unlikely to get too many extra attacks from that set up. Maces do not have wide critical threat ranges, and every crit just gives you one more attack so you only keep attacking as long as you keep critting (which you’re unlikely to do). Blood in the Water helps you hit (and therefore confirm critical hits) but it doesn’t help you actually threaten a critical in the first place.

Now, if those were +1 *keen aptitude* kukris and you had the Roundabout Kick feat, and you took levels in the Disciple of Dispater class, **then** you’d be looking at a reasonably high likelihood of literally unending attacks. Because you have both Lightning Maces and Roundabout Kick, and *aptitude* makes those both apply to your already-wide-threat-range kukris, and Disciple of Dispater is a 3.0 prestige class that (in keeping with the way 3.0 worked) expands your threat range in a way that stacks with Improved Critical or *keen*, well. You’d score a critical threat on most rolls that hit, confirm that on most rolls, and every time you did you’d get **two** extra attacks. All you need is to crit a few times in a row (not unlikely for you) to give yourself a fairly enormous pool of attacks, that is more likely to expand than it is to shrink.

And if you can find a DM who will let you run that, more power to you. For what it’s worth, Lightning Maces was banned in Test of Spite, which was a **very** high power arena game played on Giant in the Playground.

Comment: +1. The limit on this is due to the laws of probability, there's no rule that caps the extra attacks.

Comment: I know the build i need to make the threat someway wide and the threat confirmation is easy with power critical just stack it 3 times xD so antway you answered my question thx very much

Comment: . And so i forgot to say, we play with a homebrew rule where we skip the threat confirmation roll, so if you threaten you scored a crit, just for fun

Comment: @Belphegor_h Why do you have Power Critical then? Power Critical does nothing except on critical confirmation rolls. Critical confirmation is pretty easy anyway, it's getting the threat that's hard.